# What is the definition of a Calabi-Yau metric on a non-compact manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

There is a lot of important recent work on the construction of Calabi-Yau metrics on non-compact complex manifolds, such as $\mathbb{C}^n$. For example:

[1] Li, Y. *A new complete Calabi-Yau metric on $\mathbb{C}^3$.* Invent. Math. 217 (2019), no. 1, 1–34.

[2] Székelyhidi, G. *Degenerations of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and Calabi-Yau metrics.* Duke Math. J. 168 (2019), no. 14, 2651–2700.

Being a complete outsider, I have a very hard time understanding what exactly they mean by a Calabi-Yau metric on a non-compact manifold such as $\mathbb{C}^n$ (they don't seem to define it in their papers). For compact manifolds, one usually defines a Calabi-Yau metric to be a metric with holonomy in $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ (see, e.g., Joyce's book *Riemannian holonomy groups and calibrated geometries* on page 54). For simply connected manifolds, this is equivalent to a Ricci-flat Kähler metric. So is a Calabi-Yau metric on $\mathbb{C}^n$ the same as a Ricci-flat Kähler metric?

What is the definition of a Calabi-Yau metric on $\mathbb{C}^n$? Are there several equivalent definitions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two slightly different definitions.  The first is that it is a Kähler metric that is Ricci-flat, and the second is that it is a Kähler metric on a (usually connected) complex $n$-manifold with holonomy in $\mathrm{SU}(n)$.  They are equivalent in the simply-connected case, but not always in the non-simply connected case.

Some people reserve the term Calabi-Yau to mean that the holonomy is exactly equal to $\mathrm{SU}(n)$, so that, for example, the flat metric on $\mathbb{C}^n$ would not be Calabi-Yau in their terminology.  However, this is not universal.

Comment: So in the Székelyhidi and Li case, they literally just mean Ricci-flat Kähler metrics on $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: @JostSchultze:  Yes, that's right.  Of course, they are aware of Berger's result that a complete Ricci-flat Kähler metric on $\mathbb{C}^n$ that is not a product has holonomy either $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ or $\mathrm{Sp}(n/2)$ (if $n$ is even).  (Metrics on a $4n$-manifold with holonomy in $\mathrm{Sp}(n)$ are known as hyperKähler metrics.)